# Trying to make a morse code converter of user input

Tags: python

new to python and I'd like some help with morse code converter. I've seen a few posts referring to dictionaries and sets but we haven't learned those in class yet and my professor insists on programming within the range of materials that are only taught in class. This is what I've got so far,

```
morse = 

    [','== '--..--',
    '?'== '..--..', 
    '.'== '.-.-.-',
    ' '== ' ',
    '0'== '-----', 
    '1'== '.----', 
    '2'== '..---', 
    '3'== '...--', 
    '4'== '....-', 
    '5'== '.....', 
    '6'== '-....', 
    '7'== '--...', 
    '8'== '---..', 
    '9'== '----.', 
    'A'=='.-', 
    'B'=='-...', 
    'C'=='-.-.', 
    'D'=='-..', 
    'E'=='.', 
    'F'=='..-.', 
    'G'=='--.', 
    'H'=='....', 
    'I'=='..', 
    'J'=='.---', 
    'K'=='-.-', 
    'L'=='.-..', 
    'M'=='--', 
    'N'=='-.', 
    'O'=='---', 
    'P'=='.--.', 
    'Q'=='--.-', 
    'R'=='.-.', 
    'S'=='...', 
    'T'=='-', 
    'U'=='..-', 
    'V'=='...-', 
    'W'=='.--', 
    'X'=='-..-', 
    'Y'=='-.--', 
    'Z'=='--..']

userInput = input('Enter your sentence to be converted to morse code.: ')
morseOutput = ''
for i in userInput:
    morseOutput += morse[i]
print(morseOutput)
```

with this I get a TypeError, and I just can't figure out how to make this program work. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: What you are using is a `list` and not a `dict`. See python dictionaries for more info.

Comment: @MohilPatel yes, as I have mentioned in our class we haven't learned "dictionaries" yet so I can't use it.

Comment: what's your thinking behind the `==` there? that compares the string on the left to the one on the right, and the result is True/False... so the list contains only True/False.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm not sure lol but thank you for clarification

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey since you're constrained from using a dictionary I would suggest you first split your morse code array into 3 arrays one for alphabets, one for digits, and the last one for special characters.

When you loop through the input check the type using something like "isnumeric" and other type comparison functions, once you determine the type use the index of the array to access the value ( lookup ASCII codes and try to understand how you can use them with array indexes).

I understand this answer is not giving you the solution but to grow as a developer you must research on your own.

Let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: I really appreciate that you decided to point me to a general direction of the answer so that I can really learn the mechanics of such. Thank you.

Comment: @plongplong have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple errors in your code.

The correct code would be

```
morse = {',': '--..--',
    '?': '..--..', 
    '.': '.-.-.-',
    ' ': ' ',
    '0': '-----', 
    '1': '.----', 
    '2': '..---', 
    '3': '...--', 
    '4': '....-', 
    '5': '.....', 
    '6': '-....', 
    '7': '--...', 
    '8': '---..', 
    '9': '----.', 
    'A':'.-', 
    'B':'-...', 
    'C':'-.-.', 
    'D':'-..', 
    'E':'.', 
    'F':'..-.', 
    'G':'--.', 
    'H':'....', 
    'I':'..', 
    'J':'.---', 
    'K':'-.-', 
    'L':'.-..', 
    'M':'--', 
    'N':'-.', 
    'O':'---', 
    'P':'.--.', 
    'Q':'--.-', 
    'R':'.-.', 
    'S':'...', 
    'T':'-', 
    'U':'..-', 
    'V':'...-', 
    'W':'.--', 
    'X':'-..-', 
    'Y':'-.--', 
    'Z':'--..'}

userInput = input('Enter your sentence to be converted to morse code.: ')
morseOutput = ''
for i in userInput:
    morseOutput += f'{morse[i.upper()]} '
print(morseOutput)
```

the first one is you use list instead of dictionary. So if you print out the morse, you will get this

```
[False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

So the first fix is to change it to dictionary by using `{}` and `:` instead of `[]` and `==`

The second problem is that you only have the Capital version of the letter. So if you put something like `a` `b` `c`, i will not be able to find anything.

So you need to put a `str.upper()` to convert all letters to capital letters.

`morse[i.upper()]` instead of `morse[i]`

And lastly, I think morse need a space between character to make it readable as well. So adding a space between each loop would do the trick

**Edit**

I just noticed that you can only use `list`

For you can do something like this instead.

```
morse = [[',', '--..--'],
    ['?', '..--..'], 
    ['.', '.-.-.-'],
    [' ', ' '],
    ['0', '-----'], 
    ['1', '.----'], 
    ['2', '..---'], 
    ['3', '...--'], 
    ['4', '....-'], 
    ['5', '.....'], 
    ['6', '-....'], 
    ['7', '--...'], 
    ['8', '---..'], 
    ['9', '----.'], 
    ['A','.-'], 
    ['B','-...'], 
    ['C','-.-.'], 
    ['D','-..'], 
    ['E','.'], 
    ['F','..-.'], 
    ['G','--.'], 
    ['H','....'], 
    ['I','..'], 
    ['J','.---'], 
    ['K','-.-'], 
    ['L','.-..'], 
    ['M','--'], 
    ['N','-.'], 
    ['O','---'], 
    ['P','.--.'], 
    ['Q','--.-'], 
    ['R','.-.'], 
    ['S','...'], 
    ['T','-'], 
    ['U','..-'], 
    ['V','...-'], 
    ['W','.--'], 
    ['X','-..-'], 
    ['Y','-.--'], 
    ['Z''--..']]

userInput = input('Enter your sentence to be converted to morse code.: ')
morseOutput = ''
for i in userInput:
    capital = i.upper()
    
    for ch, v in morse:
        if ch == capital:
            morseOutput += f'{v} '
            break

print(morseOutput)
```